# Is the charging port in Apple's Magic mouse a design failure?

Tags: usability, design, apple, design-thinking

I have seen people bashing Apple Computer for the charging port in Magic mouse.

[image]

**The purpose of asking this question is:**

1. If this is design failure, Apple being such a huge company and credited for some of the best UX and design principles didn't saw this coming?
2. The design team responsible have not done any research, test and validation?
3. Did they ignored it?
4. Was it done with some intention, like no use while charging as it is not considered safe?

What I understand is either it was done intentionally or the team completely ignored it.

Comment: Apple used the same design as their previous magic mouse that had batteries, so probably it is more design legacy than failure. Why they didn't want to change the design in favor of "charge-while-using" is maybe to keep the ergonomics the same and make it an attractive upgrade for existing users. But I can only guess.

Comment: Without direct access to the designer(s) responsible for this, we have no way of knowing if any of our answers are actually correct. Any answers added here would be opinion based which doesn't suit the format of this site. A design discussion site might be more useful for discussion the pros and cons of this design

Answer (score 3):

Given that with just 5 minutes of charging you get around 10 hours of mouse usage and charging it to full gives you around 1 to 3 months of usage, at first it might seem that it's an aesthetic decision detrimental to usability but at a closer look there doesn't seem to be any disadvantages of having the charging on the bottom because ultimately it's a wireless mouse.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the Lightning connector is not designed for the mechanical strain of using the mouse while charging. So maybe it is to avoid warranty claims of angry customers who damaged the charging port by using the Magic mouse in an unintended way...

Answer (score 0):

My 499rs mouse provided the best design, even I can charge it and work on parallel. Apple's over thinking on UserExperience leads to poor desing.

Apple: 5 minutes of charging you get around 10 hours.
User: Lot of actions can be done in that 5mins like Ticket booking, sending email...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These days Apple often goes for design of appearance and form over design of function.

Here, the charging port being on the bottom allows a nice seamless top and front.

As others have noted, the tradeoff of five minutes of unusability was evidently judged to be worth always looking good, or something like that.

What (imo) Apple often fails to realize is that it's the smallest things that hurt the most in ease of use issues. People spend a lot of money on smart outlets not to have to walk three feet to hit a light switch, for example. And by the same token they resent those five minutes of charging (which — like all empty batteries — always come at the worst time) more than they would an hour of charging while being able to do what they want.

User wisdom (charge it when not using the computer) would solve the problem, of course, but design must always assume user stupidity and laziness to be effective.

However, another user has suggested that the charging port is a point of strain while using the mouse. This is a good theory too that runs counter to the above explanation. But I don't think Apple is smart enough to prioritize that.